# R is changing variables into NA instead of specified string

Tags: r

For some reason this code is finding all the instances where the column "label" is not == "Negative" but is replacing them with NA instead of "~Negative"... I don't know why.
The table is dcsv4 with columns labeled tweets, and label:

```
dcsv4$label[dcsv$label != "Negative"]<-"~Negative"
```

The values are other strings like "Angry", "Positive", and "Excited"...

Comment: is `dcsv4$label` a factor? ( `class(dcsv$label)`)

Comment: yes it says it is a factor

Comment: @lrrr You should convert your factors to strings. For instance, if you are reading dcsv4 from a .csv file, add `stringsAsFactors = F` to your read.csv call

Comment: okay this makes sense. I will look up how to convert every element of the column from a factor to a string. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: It worked by doing dcsv$label<-as.character(dcsv$label) Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should know about factors is that they are weird.  The chief characteristics you can consider them having are

1. They look like character strings
2. They are stored like integers
3. They act like neither

   x <- sample(c("Angry", "Positive", "Excited", "Negative"), 
               25, replace = TRUE)
   x <- factor(x)

When you attempt to make the assignment below, what you're doing is trying to overwrite an underlying numeric value with a character.  R doesn't interpret that very well, so it returns missing values.

```
x_attempt1 <- x
(x_attempt1[x_attempt1 != "Negative"] <- "~Negative")
```

A factor has two pieces.  The levels are the integer part, and they always go from 1 to n, where n is the number of levels.

The label is the part we see.

If you want to modify the appearance of the factor labels, you actually have to access the `levels` attribute

```
levels(x)
```

Don't be fooled by the function name there.  `levels` will display the labels, but the labels are sorted in ascending order of the level (so the first label is 1, the second label is 2, etc.)

If you want to alter the appearance of the label, you can do things like this:

```
x_attempt2 <- x
levels(x_attempt2) <- list("~Negative" = c("Angry", "Positive", "Excited"),
                           "Negative" = "Negative")
x_attempt2
```

Or, if you want to make life a little more comfortable, convert the factor to a character vector and then things will work as you expect them to.

```
x <- as.character(x)
x[x != "Negative"] <- "~Negative"
```

Comment: thank you. I converted to character so my tiny mind wouldnt explode.